# Backup tools for backup Linux and Windows systems with encryption

Tags: windows, backup, encryption, rsync, deja-dup

Deja Dup doesn't support full system encryption, only home directory.
rsync - I should make the backup, then archive the folder and then encrypt it. It's too long.
tar archive of the system - I should make tar, and then encrypt the archive. It's too long.
encrypt the external hard drive with cryptsetup and then put tar archive of the system there or use rsync - I can't use the standard Windows utility to make the backup because it requires ntfs.
Am I right? What would you recommend?

Comment: I found out about Clonezilla. If I will use it, can I use free space on the external hard drive?

Comment: "It's too long." Whatever option you pick: it will take as much time as rsync or tar takes. rsync has the option to make incremental backups. Maybe you should take that approach? And I myself would never create backups that are encrypted. I put backups in an actual safe :P

Answer (score 0):

Try Veeam agent for linux, it encrypts backup before sending it to the storage since v2.0. Can't say much about their windows agent though, howvere I'd expect it to have source-side encryption available too.

Answer (score 0):

Back in Time supports full system backup, and you can specify an encrypted HDD as the backup storage location. Install from the default repositories with `apt install backintime-common backintime-gnome` or try a more up-to-date version using their PPA `ppa:bit-team/stable`

BorgBackup will create encrypted backups of anything you like, including an entire disk image. Install from the default repos with `apt install borgbackup`. It also has a more up-to-date PPA version `ppa:costamagnagianfranco/borgbackup`

Read [this answer before adding PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351) so you are aware of the possible risks and benefits.

*The part of our question about Windows is off-topic here, as is asking open questions for software recommendations. If you change your title to "What Ubuntu software supports full system backups with encryption" it will be a better fit for this site, and that's what my answer deals with.*